# Which version of NDK support armv8.2-a's NEON intrinsics?

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I wanna know from which version of NDK starts, it supports armv8.2-a's NEON intrinsics,like vdot. And r25b already support.

Answer (score 1):

Every NDK in recent history does, but that's not the question that matters. OEMs are still shipping devices with SoCs that don't support those instructions. If you want your code to work on all devices, you cannot unconditionally use those intrinsics. You have to use something like https://github.com/google/cpu_features to check compatibility at runtime before calling them.

Just to be sure though: I don't think the 8.2 extensions are actually called Neon. Neon I think only refers to the older armv7 extensions, which are universally (well, not tegra 2, but that's such a vanishingly small portion of devices that I don't know anyone that bothers supporting them anymore) available. Same as before: this has nothing to do with the NDK version. The device hardware is what matters.